Checking the list for denied elements
I need validate list elements: list must contain required elements and must not contain forbidden elements. (In my example list - "cities")
I can check list for required elements with cue function list.Contains(). This function returns true , if element exists in list.
And for checking list for forbidden elements I need something, acting vice versa.
I have to validate a big amount of conf files with cuelang. So first I convert them and merge to one common json file. And then run cue vet.
all_confs.json:
{
  "/tmp/europe.yml": {
    "raw": "conf:\n  iscontinent: true\n  cities: [\"Dehli\", \"Paris\"]\n\n",
    "structure": {
      "conf": {
        "iscontinent": true,
        "cities": [
          "Dehli",
          "Paris"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "/tmp/africa.yml": {
    "raw": "conf:\n  iscontinent: true\n  cities: [\"Addis-Abeba\", \"Nairobi\", \"Paris\"]\n  ",
    "structure": {
      "conf": {
        "iscontinent": true,
        "cities": [
          "Addis-Abeba",
          "Nairobi",
          "Paris"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

Rules file static_conf.cue:
package verifylist

import "list"

[=~"/tmp/africa.yml"]: structure!: conf!: {
  ...
// check for required elements - this works perfectly
  "cities"!: list.Contains("Nairobi") & list.Contains("Addis-Abeba")
}

How can I add check for forbidden element? In this example forbidden value is "Paris".
May be there is some way to invert function result: true to false, false to true?
I find solution https://cuetorials.com/patterns/required-list-elem. But I couldn't apply it: I cannot refer list in .cue from .json. Is it possible?
I also have rather big amount for forbidden element. And I wouldn't like to overload rules code with big amnount of cycles for each forbidden element.

I suggest you to develop a Python script for this validation. The cuelang is too poor.

The following CUE schema invalidates config when Paris is in the cities list:
[=~"/tmp/africa.yml"]: structure!: conf!: {
  ...
  cities!: [for x in cities if x != "Paris" {x}]
}

The following schema invalidates config when Paris or London is in the cities list:
[=~"/tmp/africa.yml"]: structure!: conf!: {
  ...
  cities!: [for x in cities if x != "Paris" && x != "London" {x}]
}

And also using the list module:
import "list"

forbidden_cities: ["Paris", "London"]

[=~"/tmp/africa.yml"]: structure!: conf!: {
  ...
  cities!: [for x in cities if !list.Contains(forbidden_cities, x) {x}]
}


Hi, @stas-simonov! But how to inject "cities" list data inside "for" statement? Now "cities" in "cities!: [for x in cities if !list.Contains(forbidden_cities, x) {x}] " is only string, not a list with data from config.

@GulnaraN It works fine in my tests. In the invalid cases I get the output like "/tmp/africa.yml".structure.of.cities: incompatible list lengths (2 and 3) because the forbidden cities are excluded from the resulting list.

@GulnaraN What is the output of your cue vet command?

Hi, Stas! Yes, your code is really working!
I got error because I have wrapped cities clause in double-quotes. cue doesn't work properly with dash in keys, that's why I wrap all the keys and values into double-quotes. In that case I get error invalid operand "cities" (found string, want list or struct):
Without them I got incompatible list lengths (2 and 3) as expected.

@GulnaraN I advise you to avoid this "constrained" cuelang in the future.
